Razor Component OnClick
I am learning asp and have come across blazor components. I am trying to bind to a buttons on click function, however when I look online I find funcitons that look like:
<button @onclick="SelectProduct(product.Id)" ... >More Info</button>

However this code produces nothing and if I put a break point in my SelectProduct function, it is never called.
If I change it to this, which I have not seen online, it was just me playing with it:
<button onclick="@SelectProduct(product.Id)" ... >More Info</button>

Then the fucntino is called, but only on page intiallization, and it doesn't seem to be boud to the on click function. Can someone let me know how I am supposed to be doing this? The full blazor component is below.
@using Models.Entity
@using InventoryApplication.WebSite.Services
@inject JsonProductService ProductService

@{var products = ProductService.GetProducts();}

<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var product in products)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@product.DisplayName</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                    <button @onclick="SelectProduct(product.Id)"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                        data-bs-target="#productModal" 
                        class="btn btn-primary">
                        More Info
                    </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="productModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="productTitle">@selectedProduct?.DisplayName</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @if (selectedProduct != null)
                {
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">Category:  @selectedProduct.Category</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Quantity:  @selectedProduct.Quantity</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Price:    $@(selectedProduct.Price.HasValue ? selectedProduct.Price.Value.ToString("F2") : "N/A")</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    Product? selectedProduct;

    Product SelectProduct(uint Id)
    {
        return selectedProduct = ProductService.GetProducts().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
}


try using this:
<button @onclick="() => SelectProduct(product.Id)"...>More Info

Thank you, but I have tried to throw a lambda in there and it didn't do anything either. I Just tried again based on your comment and same result, the functino is never called.

Blazor/Net version?  Interactivity type?  Interactivity location?  [All set when you created the project]

And @onclick="SelectProduct(product.Id)" shouldn't compile.  You should be getting sonething like: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.

The method should return void, not Product. And you do need the lambda.

@HenkHolterman You're right. I did have it as void orginally like you would expect from a setter, I changed it to Produt to just test if it expected a value and forgot to change it back.
Changing it back to void with the lambda still results in the code never running.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis
.NET Versioin: .NET 8.0
There is no options for Blazor version when you create a ASP Razor page project, just .NET and it only ask for auth method, which I choose none, checked the box for config https, did not check the box to enable docker. Interativity type also is not an option, have not seen it anywhere.
The code @onclick="SelectProduct(product.Id)" compiles find and I used it originally since it is similar to what I found in the docs:

Ensure Correct Method Signature: Make sure the SelectProduct method signature is correct and matches the expected parameters. Ensure the method is defined correctly like this:
Product SelectProduct(uint Id) {
    return selectedProduct = ProductService.GetProducts().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
}

Verify Click Event Binding: Ensure the @onclick event binding is correctly placed within the button element and is not overridden or interfered with by other scripts or styles. Use the lambda expression @onclick="() => SelectProduct(product.Id)" to ensure correct parameter passing.
<button @onclick="() => SelectProduct(product.Id)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-primary"> More Info </button>


I setup my project as a razor page, since I was looking at an old tutorial on the microsoft tutorials. Someone asked the interactivity mode and that helped me notice. I needed to add everything from the Blazor Web App template.
